# Backup Strategy for database and file system

Tags: database, file, backup

My System is dependent on both database and file system and my file system is more than 100 gb. So while taking backup of both database and file at the same time, database backup completed within minutes and file system takes hours. In the mean time real users are working on it, add and delete file. So my backup become inconsistent with respect to the database backup.
Could anyone tell me how we can take a backup of both database and file system, to make both compatible and consistent state